# How to specify the thousands and decimals separators for the mdx query?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Currently if I run MDX queries I get the formatted values like

```
123.456.789,01
```

What I want to achieve is that (period) is used as a decimal separator and (comma) as a thousands separator.

Is there any way to specify the separators/culture globally for all queries?

Answer (score 0):

FORMAT_STRING is the standard way of altering formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx

It can be implemeted within an `mdx` script like this:

```
WITH [Measures].[aMeasureFormat] AS
  [Measures].[aMeasure]
, FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.0"  
SELECT
  {} ON 0,
  [Measures].[aMeasureFormat] ON 1
FROM [yourCube];
```

Comment: it is not what I am looking for: format_string only allows me to specify the placeholders for the separators, not the values of the separators themselves

Comment: @DmitriTsoy I do think @whytheq is on the right track. You can set the format string `#,##0.00` in the measures in the cube designer and it will work as you want. No matter the locale of the users it will be formatted that way. I assume you are currently using a format string like `Standard` which I believe will differ based upon the locale of the user.

Comment: @GregGalloway appreciate your follow up - I've never been involved with cube design (long story but a decision made by my company) so I don't know the cube designer. If you're interested in something more interesting then maybe this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401652/fast-dynamic-named-set-calculation?noredirect=1#comment68146788_40401652  .... my answer is effectively "feeling around in the dark" interested to know the user's best approach.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. However it doesn't work this way. When you specify the format_string as FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.0"  you only define the the placeholders, where "," is ALWAYS a thousands separator and "." is ALWAYS a decimal separator. Then, when the mdx is executed, depending on your/server local settings you get "," or "." as thousands and "." or "," as decimal separator. So far I could not find the way on how to force certain local/combination.

Comment: From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx): "." Represents a decimal placeholder that determines how many digits are displayed to the left and right of the decimal separator. "," Represents a thousand separator that separates thousands from hundreds within a number that has four or more places to the left of the decimal separator.

Comment: @DmitriTsoy did you try changing your settings in the cube designer as suggested by Greg ?

Comment: @DmitriTsoy ok - well if greg suggests "You can set the format string #,##0.00 in the measures in the cube designer and it will work as you want." then I suspect it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

too late but it is probably:, `LANGUAGE=1034`, `FORMAT_STRING="$#,##0.00"`
will set apropriate code page.